# Как выполнить декомпрессию массива байт в Python из GzipOutputStream Java

Tags: java, python

Выполняю компрессию с помощью GzipOutputStream в Java. И записываю в обычный JSON файл массив байт.

```
private static byte[] compress(List<Double> values) {
    String data = convertListToString(values);
    byte[] compressed = new byte[0];

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length());
        GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
        gzip.write(data.getBytes());
        gzip.close();
        compressed = bos.toByteArray();
        bos.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.warn("error compress meas");
    }

    return compressed;
}
```

Пытаюсь распаковать этот массив байт в Python 3.x Получаю ошибку

```
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

Код Python следующий:

```
def parse_measurements(self):

    arr = [i+128 for i in list]
    bytes_arr = bytearray(arr)

    g = self.stream_gzip_decompress(bytes_arr)
    for i in g:
        print(g)

    return []

def stream_gzip_decompress(self, stream):
    dec = zlib.decompressobj(32 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
    for chunk in stream:
        rv = dec.decompress(bytes(chunk))
        if rv:
            yield rv
```

В качестве параметра для `zlib.decompressobj` использовал так же `15 + 32`, но результат тот же. Отмечу, что данные использую не битые, так как Java распаковывает массив нормально.

Данную операцию уже проводил и все работало нормально, но старый скрипт затерялся, а с новым почему-то не задается никак.